# FF8 Triple Triad: Why my Blobra didn't turn both cards?

Tags: final-fantasy-8

I'm playing Android version of Final Fantasy 8's Triple Triad game.

Rules: http://tripletriad.ucoz.com/

The Blobra (on the right center) I just played have same number of top and left cards, so why they both didn't turn blue?

[image]

Comment: in the game itself there are times where you do Same but it doesn't work because Same is not in the region's ruleset (ie. Balamb, FH, Trabia). i don't know anything about this stand alone version of Triple Triad on Android so can you confirm the ruleset

Comment: @Memor-X the Same worked again this same guy, but for upper qnd lower cards. I wonder if it works for upper+left. Or maybe it's a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did post this on the app comments, and looks like someone from the dev team did answered here that this was a bug (but he didn't identified himself, was down voted and deleted the answer).

Comment: The user who commented was "SnakeULTIMATE" who does appear to be the developer, so I'm not sure why it was deleted (by an admin).

Answer (score 0):

The rules contain this line under "Chapter 2: Same":

> It requires an ally also touching the played card with the same number as well.

While this doesn't show in the sample screenshot they provided, I assume it means you must have an ally card with same number, in your case the Thrustaevis below the Blobra should have been a blue card with 1 on top and then Same would have been triggered.

Comment: Not really. When I trigger "Same" for left and right cards, for example, the card on the left match its right number to my lelft number. And the card on the the right match it's left number with my card on the right.